# Activating pom.xml additional profile depending on one property

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I'm with a pom.xml in this Java JNLP project and we have three profiles (dev, pre, pro) and besides that and independently, these two modes for running the application. One is like this:

```
<properties>
    <!-- When this is set to webservice, we need no more properties -->
    <service.mode.package>webservice</service.mode.package>
</properties>
```

and when service.mode.package changes its value, we change to this:

```
<properties>
    <!-- When this is set to localservice, we need the properties following this line -->
    <service.mode.package>localservice</service.mode.package>

    <!-- DESIRED PROPERTIES FOR LOCALSERVICE -->
    <jdbcDriver.propName>someName</jdbcDriver.propName>
    <jdbcDriver.groupId>com.some.url</jdbcDriver.groupId> 
    <jdbcDriver.version>6.9</jdbcDriver.version>

    <dataSource.id>${project.artifactId}-ds</dataSource.id> 
    <dataSource.simpleJndiName>jdbc/${dataSource.id}</dataSource.simpleJndiName>
    <dataSource.user>userName</dataSource.user> 
    <dataSource.password>someW31rdPassw0rd</dataSource.password> 

    <testDataSource.password>${dataSource.password}</testDataSource.password> 
    <testDataSource.user>${dataSource.user}</testDataSource.user>
</properties>
```

Now we're commenting and uncommenting this bunch of properties every time we change the service.mode.package value, so my question is if it's possible with Maven 3.2.1 to define a set of properties depending on the value of one specific property.

This should work changing it in one place, because any of the profiles could change his service.mode.package value. The best would be changing this value in one profile and not having to worry about all the properties depending on it.

EDIT: I've read that I can activate two profiles at once and I'm trying this after the already existing profiles:

```
    <profile>
        <id>localservice</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>service.mode.package</name>
                <value>localservice</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- DESIRED PROPERTIES FOR LOCALSERVICE -->
            <jdbcDriver.propName>someName</jdbcDriver.propName>
            <jdbcDriver.groupId>com.some.url</jdbcDriver.groupId> 
            <jdbcDriver.version>6.9</jdbcDriver.version>

            <dataSource.id>${project.artifactId}-ds</dataSource.id> 
            <dataSource.simpleJndiName>jdbc/${dataSource.id}</dataSource.simpleJndiName>
            <dataSource.user>userName</dataSource.user> 
            <dataSource.password>someW31rdPassw0rd</dataSource.password> 

            <testDataSource.password>${dataSource.password}</testDataSource.password> 
            <testDataSource.user>${dataSource.user}</testDataSource.user>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

It seems to activate only if I put in the tag !webservice and it activates always. How does this work? Does it compare the string value?

I would be grateful if someone knows what to do or where can I find the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: First if you already have so much profiles it sounds you should really think about the usage of profile if your doing it right? The question is why do you have profiles and which purpose do those profiles handle?

Comment: The profiles are used for development, pre-production and production environments. But this working mode (localservice or webservice) is independent of the environment.

Comment: I assume this is intended to use different properties for the different environments? If so you should take a look at: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin/ The other question is what kind of application do you produce? Is this a kind of micro service or just an app which installed as usual (via CLI or deployed as war/ear into Application server?) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The change in the mode is for changing the architecture from a single client accessing the DB or via a client-server. This can be one way or another in all three environments.
The app is distributed with a JNLP link.

Comment: Than you should make appropriate modules which build the needed modules with one go and don't use profiles and this make it easier to build your application with a usual: `mvn clean package` nothing more to know...conventions over configuration...